# I am getting Target class [Uploadcontroller] does not exist in laravel 9 and I don't know how to solve this

Tags: php, laravel-routing, laravel-9

**web.php**

```
    use App\Http\Controllers\Uploadcontroller;
    Route::post('/upload', [Uploadcontroller::class, 'upload']);
```

**Uploadcontroller.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Uploadcontroller extends Controller
{
    public function upload(Request $request){
    dd($request->file('image'));
    }
}
```

These are my route and controller codes. So, when I hit upload it is showing Uploadcontroller does not exist.I am new to Laravel and I don't know what is wrong here.

Comment: Check that the letters of the file name and class name are the same case. Normally I'd expect to see this as `UploadController` (with an uppercase `C`) and the filename would be `UploadController.php`

Answer (score 0):

use the command
php artisan route:clear

and the  web.php file

add in top

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UploadController;
```

Note:
Check that the letters of the file name and class name are the same case

Answer (score -1):

Your codes seems just fine.
But dont forget everytime you add a Route to the 'web.php' file you need to rebuild the routing in Laravel. 
Try run this in CMD:

```
php artisan optimize
```